# Reinstale MySQL Workbench y no me reconoce la contraseña del root

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Volví a instalar Workbench mi contraseña siempre fue "admin" (sin comillas), pero ahora que intento colocarla y dar en check me da error, alguna solucion, llevo toda la tarde buscando una solucion :c

[[image: Anexo Una Imagen1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WINDOWS**

Puedes restablecer la contraseña de root de mysql en windows de la siguiente manera:

> 1. Deten el servicio de MySQL si se está ejecutando
> 2. Crea un archivo de texto que contenga la siguiente declaración en una sola línea y guárdalo como 'C:\mysql-init.txt' :

```
set PASSWORD FOR 'root@localhost' = PASSWORD('nueva contraseña');
```

> 3. Inicia el servidor MySQL con la siguiente variable del sistema establecida para nombrar el archivo. Si instalaste MySQL en una ubicación diferente modifica la ruta en el comando CMD

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
C:\> mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

> 4. El servidor ejecuta el contenido del archivo en la variable del sistema cambiando la contraseña de root
> 5. Si instalaste MySQL utilizando el asistente como parece ser tu caso, es posible que debas especificar una opcion --defaults-file

```
C: \> mysqld
     --defaults-file = "C: \\ ProgramData \\ MySQL \\ MySQL Server 5.6 \\ my.ini"
     --init-file = C: \\ mysql-init.txt
```

> 6. Después de que el servidor se haya iniciado correctamente elimina el archivo creado C:\mysql-init.txt

Puedes ver el la documentación oficial del proceso [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.6/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

**LINUX**

> 1. Detén el servicio MySQL

```
service mysqld stop
```

o:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

> 2. Inicia el servicio mediante el siguiente comando:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking&
```

> Este comando, mediante la opción -skip-grant-tables, te permite iniciar MySQL sin el sistema de privilegios
> 3. Una vez iniciado MySQL accede con el usuario root

```
mysql -u root
```

> 4. Una vez dentro, debes acceder a la base de datos MySQL, que es donde realizaras el cambio de contraseña

```
mysql> use MySQL;
```

> 5. Ya dentro de la base de datos, podrás modificar la contraseña mediante el siguiente comando:

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('contraseña') WHERE user='root';
```

> 6. Una vez realizado deberás salir de MySQL:

```
mysql> exit
```

> 7. Por último deberás reiniciar el servicio de MySQL:

```
service mysqld restart
```

o:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```